# Why ASP.NET Web deploy re-publish everything after changing a dev machine

Tags: asp.net, webdeploy

I've encountered this issue several times, every time I change a dev machine, did a minor change, it re-publish everything even including images (jpg, png, gif), and the comparison windows shows no difference at all.

The "solution" is re-publish everything, then on this machine it will work correctly, however, once I change to another machine, same issue happen. I can't stand it any more...

Comment: When you "change a dev machine" do your file last-changed dates get changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because by default Web Deploy uses file modification dates to check if the file needs to be copied to target. When you change dev pc you re-buiold everything effectively setting file modification timestamps to a newever date, than it was when publishing from old dev machine.

As of the new [ASP.NET and Web Tools for Visual Studio 2013 Release](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/release-notes#publish) you can configure your web peoject to use checksums instead of modification timestamps. This must solve your problem. - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942158.aspx#use_checksum

Just modify your publich profile to include the following:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MSDeployUseChecksum>true</MSDeployUseChecksum>
    <!— other settings omitted to keep the example short -->
    <PublishDatabaseSettings>
      <!— this section omitted to keep the example short -->
    </PublishDatabaseSettings>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Thanks, after business trip I will verify it!